# Android Studio is there a way to add a title text above a list view item?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Like the title is there any way to make the contents of a list view be displayed with a title and a body?

I'm making a note taking app and so far i can write into a text box and save to a list view which is displayed in my main view one after the other.

I was wondering if there was any way i could do the same thing but write a title that would appear above the body of text that i already have implemented.

[image]

Comment: ListView is old and should be replaced by a RecyclerView, especially since you're working with data that can grow. Use that https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: Oh didnt know that, what about using cardview?

Comment: You can use a CardView inside a RecyclerView

Comment: look at this : https://github.com/mohosyny/MVVM_NoteApp

Comment: look at this : https://github.com/mohosyny/MVVM_NoteApp  the same implemntaion you want

Comment: Wow thanks so much guys its exactly what i was looking for. Created a cardview inside the recyclerView with two text views did exactly what i needed. :D